# How to add textview inside a node of sceneVIew in ARkit ios

Tags: ios, swift, augmented-reality, swift5, scntext

I am new in AR development and currently working with one video calling based application using AR features so need to add UITextview inside sceneview's node

I have tried with following code:

```
  let scanInfo = UITextView(frame:CGRect(x: location.x, y: location.y, width: 100, height: 80))

    scanInfo.textAlignment = .left
    scanInfo.textColor = UIColor.white
    scanInfo.text = "SCAN A SURFACE"

  sceneView.addSubview(scanInfo)
```

If anyone having some idea about then plz let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey guys I got the solution of my own question Hope this helps.

Add a plane node and inside that add SCNtext as a child node of plane node

```
sceneView.automaticallyUpdatesLighting = true
sceneView.autoenablesDefaultLighting = true
   
guard let anchor = self.makeAnchor(at: location) else {return}
   
let plane = SCNPlane(width: 50, height: 50)
plane.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.gray
    
let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
    
planeNode.scale = SCNVector3(0.0015, 0.0015, 0.0015)
planeNode.position = SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3.x ,anchor.transform.columns.3.y,anchor.transform.columns.3.z)
    
let yawn = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.y
    
planeNode.eulerAngles.y = (yawn ?? 0) + .pi * 2
planeNode.eulerAngles.x =(sceneView.session.currentFrame?.camera.eulerAngles.x ?? 0)
lastnode = planeNode
sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)


  let text = SCNText(string: textSrting, extrusionDepth: 1)
    let material = SCNMaterial()
    material.diffuse.contents = UIColor.white
    material.multiply.intensity = 0.8
    material.specular.contents = UIColor.red
    material.isDoubleSided = true

    material.locksAmbientWithDiffuse = true

    let (min, max) = lastnode!.boundingBox
    let width = CGFloat(max.x - min.x)
    let height = CGFloat(max.y - min.y)
    text.containerFrame = CGRect(x: CGFloat(min.x + 2), y: CGFloat(min.y - 2), width: (width - 3) , height: (height + 2))
    text.truncationMode = CATextLayerTruncationMode.middle.rawValue
    text.isWrapped = true
    text.alignmentMode = CATextLayerAlignmentMode.left.rawValue
    text.truncationMode = CATextLayerTruncationMode.middle.rawValue

    text.font = UIFont(name: "Proxima-nova", size: 3)
    text.materials = [material]
    
    
    let textNode = SCNNode(geometry: text)

    lastnode?.addChildNode(textNode)
```